# Cmake: Difference between Boost_INCLUDE_DIR and Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS?

Tags: ubuntu, boost, cmake

The [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) states that there is:

```
Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS     - Boost include directories
```

and later in the same documentation

```
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR         - Directory containing Boost headers
```

One with **s**, one without.

What is the difference between those two? Which one do I point to my boost installation?

Answer (score 1):

The first variant,

```
Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS     - Boost include directories
```

is among variables titled with

> results are reported in variables:

These variable are for **using** (via **read**) in the `CMakeLists.txt` after `find_package(Boost)`.

The second variant,

```
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR         - Directory containing Boost headers
```

is among variables titled with

> saves search results persistently in CMake cache entries:

That is, you may **set** this CACHE variable (e.g. with `-D` option when call `cmake`) for hint CMake about the Boost location.

But preferable way for hint CMake about Boost location is to **set** variables in the list above, titled with

> This module reads hints about search locations from variables:

When read these variables, CMake (`FindBoost.cmake` script) checks their value for correctness. E.g. it could be checked that directory stored in variable `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` **actually contains** some Boost headers.